# Formatear JSON como árbol

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un arreglo tipo json, que contiene un id y un id_padre.

Necesito pasar eso a un árbol, ejemplo:

```
[{id: 1, id_padre: null, nombre: 'algo'}, 
{id: 2, id_padre: 1, nombre: 'algo 2'}, 
{id: 3, id_padre: 2, nombre: 'algo'}]
```

Debería quedar algo como:

```
[{id: 1, id_padre: null, nombre: 'algo', 
  hijos : [{id: 2, id_padre:1, nombre: 'algo', 
                hijo: [{id: 3, id_padre:2, nombre: 'algo'}]}]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí está una posible solución.

```js
// Asumimos IDs únicos.
var list= [
  {id: 1, id_padre: null, nombre: 'algo'}, 
  {id: 2, id_padre: 1, nombre: 'algo 2'}, 
  {id: 3, id_padre: 2, nombre: 'algo'},
  {id: 4, id_padre: 5, nombre: 'algo 4'},//Agregé un par de elementos para mostrar otras posibilidades
  {id: 5, id_padre: null, nombre: 'algo 4'}
];
var listToTree = function(list){
  // Diccionario de referencias, para no tener que estar dando varias pasadas,
  // ya que no hay garantia de que los padres elementos estén ordenados por id 
  // o que los padres tengan IDs de valor menor a sus hijos.
  var dictionary = {};
  var tree = [];
  for(var i = 0;i < list.length; i++){
    var element = {};
    for(var x in list[i]){
      // Clon
      element[x] = list[i][x];
    }
    // Si existe un padre temporal, recuperamos la lista de hijos.
    element.hijos = dictionary[element.id] ? dictionary[element.id].hijos: []; 
    dictionary[element.id] = element;

    if(element.id_padre){
      // Si no existe el padre en el diccionario, creamos un padre temporal
      // Esto es parte de la estrategia para no tener que iterar varias veces
      if(!dictionary[element.id_padre]){
        dictionary[element.id_padre] = { id:element.id_padre, hijos: [] }; 
      }
      dictionary[element.id_padre].hijos.push(element);
    }
    else{
      // Es un padre y se agrega a la raiz del arbol. Se asume que pueden existir multiples padres.
      tree.push(element);
    }
  }
  return tree.length === 1 ? tree[0] : tree ;//Si solo hay un padre, se envía solo ese objeto en lugar del arreglo completo.
}


var tree = listToTree(list);

//Se formatea y se muestra el json
document.getElementById('listCode').innerText = JSON.stringify(list, null, 1);
document.getElementById('treeCode').innerText = JSON.stringify(tree, null, 1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h3>Lista</h3>
    <pre id="listCode">
    </pre>
    <h3>Arbol</h3>
    <pre id="treeCode">
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,  me haz ayudado muchísimo

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy buena y te voté positivo, sin embargo, no es recomendable responder a preguntas que no están bien formuladas, en este caso, no había código base para demostrar que AP intentó solucionarlo por su cuenta. Por favor revisa [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), especialmente, **Contesta preguntas bien formuladas**.